# MySql slow query with one join and conditions on both tables

Tags: mysql, performance, inner-join

I cannot understand why the following query is so slow:

```
select er.Id 
from employeeRequests er
inner join employees e on e.id = er.idEmployee
where er.DateTime1 >= '2017-03-11'
and er.DateTime1 <= '2018-06-10'
and er.state = 0 and e.idCompany = 37;
```

Both tables are InnoDB.
The 'employeerequests' table has 200.000 records.
The 'employees' table has 10.000.
On a fast machine the query takes almost 4 seconds to execute.

EXPLAIN returns the following lines:

```
select_type    table    type    possible_keys                         key                                  key_len    ref         rows    filtered    Extra
SIMPLE         e        ref     PRIMARY,FK_employee_idCompany_idx     FK_employee_idCompany_idx            8          const       211     100.00      Using index
SIMPLE         er       ref     FK_employeeRequest_IdEmployee_idx     FK_employeeRequest_IdEmployee_idx    8          db.e.id     77      1.11        Using where
```

I understand that "filtered = 1.11" on the second line may be the problem, but I don't know how to address it.

If I remove the join and replace it with a condition like "er.idEmployee in (1,2,...)" the query becomes really fast, but I don't like this solution and, anyway, I would like to understand why I cannot get the same result with a join.

These are the CREATE TABLE statements with all the relevant fields:

```
CREATE TABLE `employeerequests` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dateTime1` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '1899-12-31 00:00:00',
  `idEmployee` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `state` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_employeeRequest_IdEmployee_idx` (`idEmployee`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_employeeRequest_IdEmployee` FOREIGN KEY (`idEmployee`) REFERENCES `employees` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE `employees` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idCompany` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `firstName` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `lastName` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_employee_idCompany_idx` (`idCompany`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_employee_idCompany` FOREIGN KEY (`idCompany`) REFERENCES `companies` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
```

Comment: As well as the EXPLAIN, questions about performance ALWAYS require SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables.

Comment: Can you tell us on which columns you have placed indices?  This is the first thing I would check.

Comment: Thank you! I added the tables CREATE statements.

Comment: Try this: `create index idx_employeerequests_dt_st on employeerequests (datetime1, state);` and then execute `select er.id from employeerequests er where er.datetime1 between '2017-03-11' and '2018-06-10' and er.state = 0 and exists (select 1 from employees where idcompany = 37 and id = er.idemployee)`. Do you see any speed improvement?

Comment: Thank you @zedfoxus, it works wonderfully! And I cannot understand why... Even without adding the index, even leaving the JOIN, only adding the subquery "exists...", the execution time has falled to 0.235 sec. Do you know why?

Comment: Yes, I can speculate. Your original query was trying to get a 1:1 match of employee id from 2 tables. Then it was doing filtering with `where` clause. `employeerequests` was being adequately filtered. I chose to select data you needed from `employeerequests` and filter it. During the filter, I asked the query to use `exists` to match up employees (which was filtered by company 37). So, filtered data matching up with filtered data might have helped your case. I'll post an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @StefanoMontani I have also added an alternate query in my answer. Can you try that and let me know how fast that runs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these two indexes.

```
create index idx_id_company
on employees (idcompany);

create index idx_employeerequests_emp_st_dt
on employeerequests (idEmployee, state, DateTime1);
```

First one will speed up searching on employee by idcompany. Second one will take thes employee id's and will dig into employeerequests, then filter out by state and by DateTime1.
You might try to switch state and idEmployee in second index to see if it helps speeding up a little bit.
Don't try to be smart and put DateTime1 at the beginning of the index. It will just hurt your query.

Contrary to general suggestions, when creating indexes for composite queries, it is better to put first columns where selectivity is not so good. My favorites are columns with 1/0. They just split your data in half and optimizer often chooses such index even for queries, where first column is not present.

To the explanation part. When you run your query on single table, then DB engine just reads all records and filters out those that didn't match. It is slow, but for reasonable small amount of records you wouldn't know the difference.
But when you join another table then it has to read all the rows in one table, and for each row look up in second table. But because you don't have indexes it has to read the second table whole for each record from the first table. So multiply time you spent on the query when running it against single table by rows in second table and you have the resulting time.
In reality it isn't that simple. This is just simplified example.

Comment: Than you for your interesting response!
The first index you propose is already there, because I have an Index and a Foreign Key on "idCompany".
But the second one solves my problem. After adding it, the query with the join runs almost instantly! Switching "state" and "idEmployee" does not change nothing with this number of records. And removing "dateTime1" from the key, makes the query only a little slower.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select er.id
from employeerequests er
where er.datetime1 between '2017-03-11' and '2018-06-10'
    and er.state = 0
    and exists (select 1 from employees where idcompany = 37 and id = er.idemployee);
```

You may be able to add some more speed by creating a composite index like so:

```
create index idx_employeerequests_dt_st
on employeerequests (datetime1, state);

create index idx_employees_id_company
on employees (id, idcompany);
```

Since your need is to get an ID from `employeerequests`, the query is primarily looking at that table and filtering the table also. `Exists` checks the existence of that particular employee in `employees` master table, which is filtered by company of choice. Both tables now are doing comparisons on reduced/filtered dataset and that may help your speed.

**Crude explanation/speculation**

The original query is like taking two stacks of paper. Pick matching papers from both stacks and create a new stack of papers. This stack may have many matching papers. From this new stack of many papers, select by filtering only those that match a date range, company and state. That's the data you need. The issue might be that you're filtering from a large 3rd stack.

Modified query is looking at first stack (of `employeerequests`) and choosing only papers with a certain state from a fixed date range. That's a smaller subset of papers. While picking up each paper, you'd check the other stack (`employees`) to see if the chosen paper has employeeid and company matching from `employees` stack. If it is, select that data. So, the modified query is just looking at smaller stacks of data resulting from filtering. Again, that's a speculation.

**Confirm yourself**

You should do an `EXPLAIN select ...` on your original query and the query above to see what MySQL is choosing for indexes and how well filtering is happening.

**Alternate query**

You can give this a shot also and see what results you get:

```
select er.Id 
from employeeRequests er
inner join employees e on 
    e.id = er.idEmployee
    and er.DateTime1 between '2017-03-11' and '2018-06-10'
    and er.state = 0
    and e.idCompany = 37;
```

Comment: Maybe that the subquery is run on the already filtered rows of the first table? What follows is the (stripped) result of the Explain of your query:
select_type         table      type     key       ref                filtered  Extra
    PRIMARY             er         ALL                                   1.11      Using where
    DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  employees  eq_ref   PRIMARY   db.er.idEmployee   5.00      Using where
(I'm sorry, because your response has been helpfull, but I have to accept another answer wich answer more precisly to the original question).

Comment: Sure, I agree with your choice of selecting an adequate answer for your question.